# About Function composition order of execution in Haskell

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I have some trouble understanding this example:

```
data Row = R [Int]
    deriving Show
data Matrix = M [Row]
    deriving Show

check :: Matrix -> Int -> Bool
check (M matrix) n = foldr ((&&) . (\(R row) -> length row == n)) True matrix


test1 = check (M[R[1,2,3], R[4,5], R[2,3,6,8], R[8,5,3]]) 3 == False
```

I have this datatype named `Row` that contains a list of integers, and the `Matrix` datatype containing a list of rows. I have to check through my function if all rows have the length equal to the second parameter, `n`. I do not really understand why that `foldr` works. Let's look at `test1`. It starts by doing  `((&&) . (lambda)) R[8, 5, 3] True`
Isn't now, some sort of (f.g) x y which is f (g x y) ? If it is so, the result will be `&&(lambda R[8, 5, 3]  True)` <->  `&& (True True)`, and Isn't the expresion in the paranthese evaluated first (`True True`) and it should give me an error ? Please make me understand what the order of execution is and where am I wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let us remember what `foldr` does: It takes a function `f`, a list `xn = [x1, x2, ..., xn]` and a starting value `s` and generates the expression

```
f x1 (f x2 (... (f xn s) ...))
```

or equivalently

```
f x1 $ f x2 $ ... $ f xn $ s
```

The function composition `(.)` first applies the right-hand side function and then the left-hand side function, so first your lambda expression, that we call `checkRow` for now and then `(&&)`. This results in

```
(&&) (checkRow x1) $ (&&) (checkRow x2) $ ... $ (&&) (checkRow xn) $ True
```

when inserting `True` as your starting value.

This can be rewritten in infix notation as

```
(checkRow x1) && (checkRow x2) && ... (checkRow xn) && True
```

Edit: Regarding how function composition works in this case, please take a look at the types:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Keep in mind that `(&&)` can be seen as an unary function that returns another (in this case unary) function and follow the types:

```
(Bool -> (Bool -> Bool)) -> (Row -> Bool) -> Row -> Bool -> Bool

(&&) . checkRow :: Row -> Bool -> Bool
```

So the composition of `(&&)` and `checkRow` is a function that takes a `Row` and a `Bool` and returns a `Bool`. So the right-hand side function is applied to the first input argument and the result is forwarded as the first input argument of the second function. The second function, however, can take multiple arguments.

This lines up nicely with the type of `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

or in your case

```
(Row -> Bool -> Bool) -> Bool -> [Row] -> Bool
```

Comment: So is it safe to generally assume that generally, ```(f . g) x y```, is, mathematically speaking, f (g(x), y)?

Comment: @Johnny Yes. In Haskell notation, we have `(f.g) x` equal to `f (g x)`, hence `(f.g) x y` is equal to `f (g x) y` ( _not_ `f (g x y)`). Note how `y` is passed to `f`, not `g`!

Comment: (f.g) x y = (f.g x) y = f(g(x)) y = f g(x) y, in the meantime I was writting a simple proof, it is pretty much the same, thanks

Comment: @Johnny What you wrote is correct, but note that in Haskell those expressions are parsed differently from what you intended. In Haskell, `f.g x` means `f . (g x)`, and `f g(x) y` means `f g x y`, i.e. `(((f g) x) y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be related to understanding what the function used in the fold actually does:

```
(&&) . (\(R row) -> length row == n)
```

Indeed, it is a bit cryptic. Let's try to rewrite it in an equivalent form. By definition of composition, `a.b` means `\x -> a (b x)`, hence we get

```
\x -> (&&) ( (\(R row) -> length row == n) x )
```

This still looks weird, since we'd like `&&` to be applied to *two* arguments. We can eta-expand: `f` is equivalent to `\y -> f y`. We get

```
\x -> \y -> (&&) ( (\(R row) -> length row == n) x ) y
```

which means

```
\x y ->  ( (\(R row) -> length row == n) x ) && y
```

Note the types: here `x :: Row`, while `y :: Bool`. We can equivalently rewrite the above as

```
\(R row) y ->  length row == n && y
```

This means that the fold

```
foldr ((&&) . (\(R row) -> length row == n)) True [Row r1, Row r2, ...]
```

simplifies to

```
length r1 == n && (length r2 == n && ... (... && True))
```

which amounts to checking that all rows have the same length `n`.